# Why would Google Analytics report slow loading times when other website testing tools show it is very fast?

Tags: google-analytics, performance, page-speed, google-pagespeed

I have a WordPress website that is well optimized on Pingdom, GTMetrix, and GPI. When I check on Analytics Speed timings some of its pages have an average load time speed of more than 3 seconds, you can check the screenshot here:
[image]

This is the speed result from Pingdom:
[image]

GTMetrix:
[image]

GPI Mobile and Desktop:
[image]
[image]

Can you help me identify how this happened and what speed I can take to lower the load time? I try to do independent research on Google yet some of the results are too generic or too old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The average page load time in Analytics shows actual user experience data based on network, server, and browser time for multiple visitors. For example, if you are receiving traffic from Zambia ([which has a low Core Web Vital value](https://ahrefs.com/blog/core-web-vitals-study/)) your average page load time in Analytics will be negatively affected. The same will apply for users browsing with 3G or older browsers.

[image]

Pingdom, GTMetrix, or GPI show a result based on optimal conditions (or at least the ones you select before the test) so it differs from the data shown in Analytics.

You are comparing the best scenario vs reality.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So it is only normal to get a high average load time speed in analytics and is there steps we can take to get a low average load time speed? We are only filtering the data from one Australia.

Comment: Yes, we usually get higher values in Analytics than in other tools, so that's normal. You can use custom segments to identify the worst performing browsers, networks and pages in order to execute specific actions to improve the performance of those segments.